# How do i add children to Firebase player UID?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I tried to add children nodes to a player with UID. I used child("node_1"). It creates only one node. How do I add items to this node?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, you need to have a `unique identifier` every time you try to add data to your database. Because a Firebase database is a NoSQL database and is structured as pairs of key and values, every node is a Map, which means in the case of Map, it replaces the old value with the new one.

Fortunately Firebase provides a method named `push()`. You can use it like this:

```
yourRef.push().child(name).setValue("John");
```

Answer (score 0):

Which one you use add child node? Web, Ios or Android?

Alex Mamo was right: "you need to have a unique identifier every time you try to add data to your database"

Using for Web:

```
let node = firebase.database().ref().child(Your node)
var key= node.push().key //  Get a key for a new
node.child(key).set(new value)
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write?authuser=0

Using for IOS:

```
let key = ref.child("posts").childByAutoId().key
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write?authuser=0

And for Android:

```
String key = mDatabase.child("posts").push().getKey()
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write?authuser=0

Hope to help you.